# how to shuffle list song with Media Player android

Tags: android, loops, media-player, shuffle

I've done shuffle in mediaplayer for a list of songs but dos not correct work please help:

```
@Override
  public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {

        if (isShuffle) {
          if (intent.hasExtra("songIndex")) {
            Random random = new Random();
            songIndex = random.nextInt((songList.size() - 1) + 1);
            playSongWithIndex(songIndex);
          }
        }
      }
```

and method for play song :

```
public void playSongWithIndex(final int songIndex) {
    progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    if (music_exist.exists()) {
      playMusicOfflineMode();
    } else {
      Log.e("TAG", "playSongWithIndex: "+songList.get(songIndex).getFile_128() );
      try {
        G.mediaPlayer.reset();
        G.mediaPlayer.setDataSource(songList.get(songIndex).getFile_128());
        G.mediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
        G.mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
          @Override
          public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
              @Override
              public void run() {
                setAdapterLyric(songManager.showTextInRecyclerView(songList.get(songIndex).getLyric()));

              }
            });
            G.mediaPlayer.start();
            music_name_text.setText(songList.get(songIndex).getEn_name());
            singer_name_text.setText(songList.get(songIndex).getSinger_name_en());
            comment_count_text.setText(songList.get(songIndex).getComment_count() + "");
            like_count_text.setText(songList.get(songIndex).getLike_count() + "");
            play_music_img.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_pause_black_24dp);
            seekBar.setMax(G.mediaPlayer.getDuration());
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            play_music_img.setEnabled(true);
            timer = new Timer();
            timer.schedule(new MainTimer(), 0, 1000);

          }
        });
      } catch (IllegalArgumentException | IllegalStateException | IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
    }
  }
```

and I was faced with this log :

```
E/TAG: playSongWithIndex: http://cdn.oneremind.com/up/song/Modern_Talking/Let's_Talk_About_Love/04_Let's_Talk_About_Love.mp3
E/TAG: playSongWithIndex: http://cdn.oneremind.com/up/song/Modern_Talking/Let's_Talk_About_Love/03_Don't_Give_Up.mp3
E/TAG: playSongWithIndex: http://cdn.oneremind.com/up/song/Modern_Talking/Let's_Talk_About_Love/04_Let's_Talk_About_Love.mp3
E/TAG: playSongWithIndex: http://cdn.oneremind.com/up/song/Modern_Talking/Let's_Talk_About_Love/03_Don't_Give_Up.mp3
E/TAG: playSongWithIndex: http://cdn.oneremind.com/up/song/Modern_Talking/Let's_Talk_About_Love/04_Let's_Talk_About_Love.mp3
E/TAG: playSongWithIndex: http://cdn.oneremind.com/up/song/Modern_Talking/Let's_Talk_About_Love/01_Cheri_Cheril_Lady.mp3
E/TAG: playSongWithIndex: http://cdn.oneremind.com/up/song/Modern_Talking/Let's_Talk_About_Love/01_Cheri_Cheril_Lady.mp3
E/TAG: playSongWithIndex: http://cdn.oneremind.com/up/song/Modern_Talking/Let's_Talk_About_Love/02_With_A_Little_Love.mp3
E/TAG: playSongWithIndex: http://cdn.oneremind.com/up/song/Modern_Talking/Let's_Talk_About_Love/03_Don't_Give_Up.mp3
E/TAG: playSongWithIndex: http://cdn.oneremind.com/up/song/Modern_Talking/Let's_Talk_About_Love/02_With_A_Little_Love.mp3
E/TAG: playSongWithIndex: http://cdn.oneremind.com/up/song/Modern_Talking/Let's_Talk_About_Love/03_Don't_Give_Up.mp3
E/TAG: playSongWithIndex: http://cdn.oneremind.com/up/song/Modern_Talking/Let's_Talk_About_Love/02_With_A_Little_Love.mp3
E/TAG: playSongWithIndex: http://cdn.oneremind.com/up/song/Modern_Talking/Let's_Talk_About_Love/02_With_A_Little_Love.mp3
E/TAG: playSongWithIndex: http://cdn.oneremind.com/up/song/Modern_Talking/Let's_Talk_About_Love/02_With_A_Little_Love.mp3
E/TAG: playSongWithIndex: http://cdn.oneremind.com/up/song/Modern_Talking/Let's_Talk_About_Love/03_Don't_Give_Up.mp3
E/TAG: playSongWithIndex: http://cdn.oneremind.com/up/song/Modern_Talking/Let's_Talk_About_Love/03_Don't_Give_Up.mp3
E/TAG: playSongWithIndex: http://cdn.oneremind.com/up/song/Modern_Talking/Let's_Talk_About_Love/01_Cheri_Cheril_Lady.mp3
E/TAG: playSongWithIndex: http://cdn.oneremind.com/up/song/Modern_Talking/Let's_Talk_About_Love/01_Cheri_Cheril_Lady.mp3
E/TAG: playSongWithIndex: http://cdn.oneremind.com/up/song/Modern_Talking/Let's_Talk_About_Love/04_Let's_Talk_About_Love.mp3
E/TAG: playSongWithIndex: http://cdn.oneremind.com/up/song/Modern_Talking/Let's_Talk_About_Love/01_Cheri_Cheril_Lady.mp3
E/TAG: playSongWithIndex: http://cdn.oneremind.com/up/song/Modern_Talking/Let's_Talk_About_Love/04_Let's_Talk_About_Love.mp3
E/TAG: playSongWithIndex: http://cdn.oneremind.com/up/song/Modern_Talking/Let's_Talk_About_Love/01_Cheri_Cheril_Lady.mp3
E/TAG: playSongWithIndex: http://cdn.oneremind.com/up/song/Modern_Talking/Let's_Talk_About_Love/02_With_A_Little_Love.mp3
E/TAG: playSongWithIndex: http://cdn.oneremind.com/up/song/Modern_Talking/Let's_Talk_About_Love/03_Don't_Give_Up.mp3
E/TAG: playSongWithIndex: http://cdn.oneremind.com/up/song/Modern_Talking/Let's_Talk_About_Love/01_Cheri_Cheril_Lady.mp3
E/TAG: playSongWithIndex: http://cdn.oneremind.com/up/song/Modern_Talking/Let's_Talk_About_Love/02_With_A_Little_Love.mp3
E/TAG: playSongWithIndex: http://cdn.oneremind.com/up/song/Modern_Talking/Let's_Talk_About_Love/01_Cheri_Cheril_Lady.mp3
E/TAG: playSongWithIndex: http://cdn.oneremind.com/up/song/Modern_Talking/Let's_Talk_About_Love/02_With_A_Little_Love.mp3
E/TAG: playSongWithIndex: http://cdn.oneremind.com/up/song/Modern_Talking/Let's_Talk_About_Love/03_Don't_Give_Up.mp3
E/TAG: playSongWithIndex: http://cdn.oneremind.com/up/song/Modern_Talking/Let's_Talk_About_Love/04_Let's_Talk_About_Love.mp3
```

and Media Player is stuck in a loop ,dos not work where is my problem?

Comment: you can use like this    Collections.shuffle(arrlist);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not create Media player with this way?

```
 G.mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this,Uri.parse("YourFilePath");//this is a context
 //Then start it without preparation.
 G.mediaPlayer.start();
```

Comment: Can you tell me what error you get when you tried this method?

Comment: I mean try the code i'v write and if you have tried it and didn't work please write the error.

Comment: your code one time work in second time mediaplayer when finished not play again `if (isShuffle) {
      if (intent.hasExtra("songIndex")) {
        Random random = new Random();
        songIndex = random.nextInt((songList.size() - 1) + 1);
        G.mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this,Uri.parse(songList.get(songIndex).getFile_128()));
        G.mediaPlayer.start();
      }
    }`

Comment: try to stop and release the player then use the code.

Comment: i do the same but second time it has a problem `if (isShuffle) {
      if (intent.hasExtra("songIndex")) {
        Random random = new Random();
        songIndex = random.nextInt((songList.size() - 1) + 1);
        G.mediaPlayer.stop();
        G.mediaPlayer.release();
       
        G.mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this,Uri.parse(songList.get(songIndex).getFile_128()));//this is a context
        G.mediaPlayer.start();
        seekBar.setMax(G.mediaPlayer.getDuration());
        G.timer.schedule(new MainTimer(),0,1000);

        
      }
    }`

Comment: Does just not playing again or give you an error? Check you log

Comment: Can you debug your code and know what's happening.And please check your logcat maybe you will see an error

Comment: in first time shuffle work , but in second time when seekbar finish or media stop and nothing happen in log cat : `E/MP3Extractor: Unable to resync. Signalling end of stream.
I/NuPlayer: audio discontinuity (formatChange=0, time=1)
W/AudioTrack: releaseBuffer() track 0xb4e0c800 disabled due to previous underrun, restarting
E/MP3Extractor: Unable to resync. Signalling end of stream.
I/AudioFlinger: BUFFER TIMEOUT: remove(4096) from active list on thread 0xb61b8000
W/ProcessCpuTracker: Skipping unknown process pid 7652
`

Comment: Could you write your file as hardcoded path,Maybe shuffleing is not work well.We need to know where's the problem.

Comment: can you join me with team viewer and help me

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144975/discussion-between-ahmed-ali-and-hadi-khezrpor).

Comment: Solved with setting listener again `G.mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(this)`

Answer (score 2):

Use collections shullfe:

```
long seed = System.nanoTime();
Collections.shuffle(songList, new Random(seed));
```